# Centering after media querie

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive, center

Tried many things to center the divs when the width has a max-width of 1124. 
"@media only screen and (max-width: 1124px)"

None of the things I did work. It stays on the left side of the screen whatever I do.
Does any of you have any idea to center it?

Thank you.

[Codepen.io Link](https://codepen.io/wingho/pen/RwPKzWb)

```css
.offer-title {
  margin-top: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 14px;
  text-align: center;
}

.container-offers {
  margin-top: 14px;
  margin-left: 4%;
  margin-right: 4%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.offer {
  min-height: 680px;
  background-color: #edf6fc;
  width: 340px;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 14px;
}

.what-included {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  margin-top: 14px;
}

.check-list {
  margin-top: 14px;
}

.price-offer {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 14px;
}

.button-offer {
  border-radius: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 17px 34px 17px;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  border: 1px solid dodgerblue;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: transform 0.2s;
  margin-top: 14px;
}

.button-offer:hover {
  background-color: #db6307;
  transform: scale(1.1);
  border: 1px solid #db6307;
  color: #000000;
  font-weight: bold;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1124px) {
  .container-offers {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 class="offer-title">  Lorem ipsum</h1>

    <div class="container-offers">
    
     <div class="offer"> 
    
    <h3 class="offer-budget"> Lorem ipsum </h3>

     <div class="what-included">
       
  <p class="check-list"><i class="far fa-check-square" style="color:green;"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
       
 <p class="check-list"><i class="far fa-check-square" style="color:green;"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
       
 <p class="check-list"><i class="far fa-check-square" style="color:green;"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
       
 <p class="check-list"><i class="far fa-check-square" style="color:green;"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
       
  <p class="check-list"><i class="far fa-check-square" style="color:green;"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
       
 <p class="check-list"><i class="far fa-check-square" style="color:green;"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
       
 <p class="check-list"><i class="far fa-check-square" style="color:green;"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
       
  <p class="check-list"><i class="far fa-times-circle" style="color:red;"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
       
  <p class="check-list"><i class="far fa-times-circle" style="color:red;"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
       
 <p class="check-list"> <i class="far fa-times-circle" style="color:red;"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>

  <p class="price-offer"> Price:  </p>

     <div class="container-button-offer">
                
   <button class="button-offer"> Lorem      ipsum </button>
       
        </div> 
           </div>
              </div>

    <div class="offer"> 

<h3 class="offer-standard"> Lorem ipsum</h3>

        <div class="what-included">
  <p class="check-list"><i class="far fa-check-square" style="color:green;"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
          
  <p class="check-list"><i class="far fa-check-square" style="color:green;"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
          
  <p class="check-list"><i class="far fa-check-square" style="color:green;"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
          
 <p class="check-list"><i class="far fa-check-square" style="color:green;"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
          
  <p class="check-list"><i class="far fa-check-square" style="color:green;"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
          

 <p class="check-list"><i class="far fa-check-square" style="color:green;"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
          
 <p class="check-list"><i class="far fa-check-square" style="color:green;"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
          
 <p class="check-list"><i class="far fa-check-square" style="color:green;"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
          
 <p class="check-list"><i class="far fa-times-circle" style="color:red;"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
          
 <p class="check-list"><i class="far fa-times-circle" style="color:red;"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>

  <p class="price-offer"> Price:  </p>
  <div class="container-button-offer">
                
  <button class="button-offer"> Lorem ipsum </button>
         </div> 
            </div>
               </div>


    <div class="offer"> 

<h3 class="offer-premium"> Lorem ipsum</h3>

        <div class="what-included">
 <p class="check-list"><i class="far fa-check-square" style="color:green;"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
          
 <p class="check-list"><i class="far fa-check-square" style="color:green;"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
          
 <p class="check-list"><i class="far fa-check-square" style="color:green;"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
          
 <p class="check-list"><i class="far fa-check-square" style="color:green;"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
          
            <p class="check-list"><i class="far fa-check-square" style="color:green;"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
          
 <p class="check-list"><i class="far fa-check-square" style="color:green;"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
          
 <p class="check-list"><i class="far fa-check-square" style="color:green;"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
          
 <p class="check-list"><i class="far fa-check-square" style="color:green;"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
          
 <p class="check-list"><i class="far fa-check-square" style="color:green;"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
          
 <p class="check-list"><i class="far fa-check-square" style="color:green;"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>

 <p class="price-offer"> Price:  </p>
 <div class="container-button-offer">
                
 <button class="button-offer"> Lorem ipsum  </button>
     </div> 
       </div>
         </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) to any third party site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the .offer styles for this ressolutions.

Use this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1124px){
  .container-offers {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .offer {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `align-items: center;` on

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1124px){
.container-offers {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    align-items: center;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.offer-title {
  margin-top: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 14px;
  text-align: center;
}

.container-offers {
  margin-top: 14px;
  margin-left: 4%;
  margin-right: 4%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.offer {
  min-height: 680px;
  background-color: #edf6fc;
  width: 340px;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 14px;
}

.what-included {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  margin-top: 14px;
}

.check-list {
  margin-top: 14px;
}

.price-offer {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 14px;
}

.button-offer {
  border-radius: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 17px 34px 17px;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  border: 1px solid dodgerblue;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: transform 0.2s;
  margin-top: 14px;
}

.button-offer:hover {
  background-color: #db6307;
  transform: scale(1.1);
  border: 1px solid #db6307;
  color: #000000;
  font-weight: bold;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1124px) {
  .container-offers {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 class="offer-title">  Lorem ipsum</h1>

    <div class="container-offers">
    
     <div class="offer"> 
    
    <h3 class="offer-budget"> Lorem ipsum </h3>

     <div class="what-included">
       
  <p class="check-list"><i class="far fa-check-square" style="color:green;"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
       
 <p class="check-list"><i class="far fa-check-square" style="color:green;"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
       
 <p class="check-list"><i class="far fa-check-square" style="color:green;"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
       
 <p class="check-list"><i class="far fa-check-square" style="color:green;"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
       
  <p class="check-list"><i class="far fa-check-square" style="color:green;"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
       
 <p class="check-list"><i class="far fa-check-square" style="color:green;"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
       
 <p class="check-list"><i class="far fa-check-square" style="color:green;"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
       
  <p class="check-list"><i class="far fa-times-circle" style="color:red;"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
       
  <p class="check-list"><i class="far fa-times-circle" style="color:red;"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
       
 <p class="check-list"> <i class="far fa-times-circle" style="color:red;"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>

  <p class="price-offer"> Price:  </p>

     <div class="container-button-offer">
                
   <button class="button-offer"> Lorem      ipsum </button>
       
        </div> 
           </div>
              </div>

    <div class="offer"> 

<h3 class="offer-standard"> Lorem ipsum</h3>

        <div class="what-included">
  <p class="check-list"><i class="far fa-check-square" style="color:green;"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
          
  <p class="check-list"><i class="far fa-check-square" style="color:green;"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
          
  <p class="check-list"><i class="far fa-check-square" style="color:green;"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
          
 <p class="check-list"><i class="far fa-check-square" style="color:green;"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
          
  <p class="check-list"><i class="far fa-check-square" style="color:green;"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
          

 <p class="check-list"><i class="far fa-check-square" style="color:green;"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
          
 <p class="check-list"><i class="far fa-check-square" style="color:green;"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
          
 <p class="check-list"><i class="far fa-check-square" style="color:green;"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
          
 <p class="check-list"><i class="far fa-times-circle" style="color:red;"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
          
 <p class="check-list"><i class="far fa-times-circle" style="color:red;"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>

  <p class="price-offer"> Price:  </p>
  <div class="container-button-offer">
                
  <button class="button-offer"> Lorem ipsum </button>
         </div> 
            </div>
               </div>


    <div class="offer"> 

<h3 class="offer-premium"> Lorem ipsum</h3>

        <div class="what-included">
 <p class="check-list"><i class="far fa-check-square" style="color:green;"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
          
 <p class="check-list"><i class="far fa-check-square" style="color:green;"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
          
 <p class="check-list"><i class="far fa-check-square" style="color:green;"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
          
 <p class="check-list"><i class="far fa-check-square" style="color:green;"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
          
            <p class="check-list"><i class="far fa-check-square" style="color:green;"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
          
 <p class="check-list"><i class="far fa-check-square" style="color:green;"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
          
 <p class="check-list"><i class="far fa-check-square" style="color:green;"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
          
 <p class="check-list"><i class="far fa-check-square" style="color:green;"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
          
 <p class="check-list"><i class="far fa-check-square" style="color:green;"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
          
 <p class="check-list"><i class="far fa-check-square" style="color:green;"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>

 <p class="price-offer"> Price:  </p>
 <div class="container-button-offer">
                
 <button class="button-offer"> Lorem ipsum  </button>
     </div> 
       </div>
         </div>
            </div>
```